# Pandas, index is a tuple (name, date), sort by date range?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas table like this:

```
f.tail()
                   Close    High    Low   Open    Volume
Symbol Date                                             
F      2017-05-18  10.79  10.820  10.70  10.73  37890246
       2017-05-19  10.87  10.940  10.79  10.81  32429488
       2017-05-22  11.10  11.130  10.98  11.11  73301992
```

And I can index using

```
f.ix[('F', date(2017,5,18))]
```

What I cant figure out is how to query an index range from this kind of an index?

Comment: Your question says you want to sort by date range but your text is asking about slicing... BTW: you can of course `f.sort_index(level=1)` to sort your dates before slicing (but they already look sorted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly call `slice`, e.g.:

```
In []:
f.loc[('F', slice(pd.datetime(2017,5,18), pd.datetime(2017,5,20))),]

Out[]:
                   Close   High    Low   Open    Volume
Symbol Date                                            
F      2017-05-18  10.79  10.82  10.70  10.73  37890246
       2017-05-19  10.87  10.94  10.79  10.81  32429488
```

Note: `ix()` is deprecated use `loc()`

Comment: Both answers are really good and work. I going with this one since it uses the pd.datetime, which I suspect may make dates explicit.

Answer (score 1):

Using `pd.IndexSlice`

```
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice['F','2017-05-18':'2017-05-20'],:] # notice here I am using 2017-05-20 
Out[42]: 
                   Close   High    Low   Open    Volume
Symbol Date                                            
F      2017-05-18  10.79  10.82  10.70  10.73  37890246
       2017-05-19  10.87  10.94  10.79  10.81  32429488
```